# How can I express a given matrix in a multiplication form?

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a following matrix:

$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
f(1,1)g(1,1) & f(1,2)g(1,2) & \cdots & f(1,d)g(1,d) \\
f(2,1)g(2,1) & f(2,2)g(2,2) & \cdots & f(2,d)g(2,d) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(n,1)g(n,1) & f(n,2)g(n,2) & \cdots & f(n,d)g(n,d)
\end{bmatrix}
$

I want to express $X=FG$, where $F$ contains only $f(\cdot)$ and $G$ contains only $g(\cdot)$, and don't want to use elementwise multiplication, just want to use matrix multiplication.

Is it possible to do so. And if so, how are $F$ and $G$ defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$,$F$ and $G$ should be square matrices it is impossible (you should be able to prove this using the determinant $\det(X)=\det(F)\det(G)$).

But if you allow $F$ and $G$ to be very large matrices, the answer is yes. For example for $n=d=2$, you can write
$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}f(1,1)g(1,1) & f(1,2)g(1,2)\\f(2,1)g(2,1)&f(2,2)g(2,2)\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}f(1,1) & f(1,2) & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & f(2,1) & f(2,2) \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}g(1,1) & 0\\0 & g(1,2) \\ g(2,1)& 0 \\ 0 & g(2,2)\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$